# How to plot multiple 1D distributed heat maps as bars on a single plot?

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn, visualization

Essentially, I am trying to convert multiple histograms to 1D heatmap "bars" on a single plot, as seen in the image below.

[image]

I'm not too sure where to start, as I'm not very used to data visualization and have only dabbled a little in matplotlib and seaborn.

I've made some progress in making something, but it's definitely not what I have been looking for.

```py
# Define the arrays
foo = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1, 0])
bar = np.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0])
baz = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])

# Define the corresponding bin labels
bin_labels = ['0.0-0.2', '0.2-0.4', '0.4-0.6', '0.6-0.8', '0.8-1.0']

# Concatenate the arrays vertically
combined_data = np.vstack((foo, bar, baz))

# Create the histogram plot
# sns.heatmap(combined_data, cmap='YlGnBu', annot=True, fmt='d', xticklabels=bin_labels, cbar=False)
sns.heatmap(combined_data, cmap='Blues', fmt='d', xticklabels=bin_labels, yticklabels=["foo","bar","baz"], cbar=True)
plt.xlabel('Counts')
plt.ylabel('Type')
plt.title('Counts Heatmap')

# Display the plot
plt.show()
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can create a matplotlib stacked bar chart where the heights of each segment is the same but you change the colors based on the percentages.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

plt.close("all")

group_names = ["foo", "bar", "baz"]
bin_labels = ["0.0-0.2", "0.2-0.4", "0.4-0.6", "0.6-0.8", "0.8-1.0"]

foo = np.array([0, 2, 3, 1, 0])
bar = np.array([0, 0, 2, 1, 0])
baz = np.array([0, 1, 1, 0, 0])
groups = [foo, bar, baz]

combined = np.vstack(groups)
percentages = combined.T/np.sum(combined, axis=1)

# creates the cmap that is normalized to the observed range
cmap = plt.get_cmap("Blues")
norm = plt.Normalize(np.min(percentages), np.max(percentages))
color = lambda c: cmap(norm(c))

# each bar is the same height and only differs by color
fig, ax = plt.subplots()
for i, p in enumerate(percentages):
    ax.bar(group_names, 1, bottom=i, width=0.5, color=color(p))

ax.set_yticks(ticks=np.arange(0.5, len(bin_labels) + 0.5)) 
ax.set_yticklabels(bin_labels)
fig.colorbar(plt.cm.ScalarMappable(cmap=cmap, norm=norm), ax=ax)
fig.show()
```

[image]

It might be a little clearer if you added `edgecolor="lightgray"` to the bar plot calls, but that's up to you.

[image]

Comment: Thank you! That fixed the problem. I initially encountered a `TypeError: Axis.set_ticks() got an unexpected keyword argument 'labels'`, but it worked after I did `ax.set_yticks(ticks=np.arange(0.5, len(bin_labels) + 0.5))
ax.set_yticklabels(bin_labels)`

Comment: @DarrellRevis I updated the code to split them up. It's probably due to a difference in matplotlib versions. If this answers your question then you can click the gray check next to my answer to accept it and turn it into a green check.